# Truncate some part in URL field

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view that consist of *username* field and *URL* field. URL is like https://www.example.com/video/video_id.

When I add the URL field, it shows the full URL; I want to display only the video_id.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for this;

1. You can simply make a `.tpl` file of view and use following code to extract only *video_id* from *URL* field.

   ```
   $url = "YUOR_URL_FIELD";
   $vid = explode('/',$url);
   echo $vid[count($vid)-1];
   ```
2. Use the [Views Php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module and add a *php field* after the *URL* field, then use this code to just show the *video_id* from *URL*.(It also needs [token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module to be enabled)

   ```
   $url = "USE_YOUR_FIELD_TOKEN";`
   $vid = explode('/',$url);
   echo $vid[count($vid)-1];`
   ```